# Select and display a certain value in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frame columns and I was wondering how do I select and return only the 'compound' value?

Data frame:

```
    attributes                                                  categories
0   {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}       {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}
1   {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.865, 'pos': 0.135, 'compound': 0.0}   {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}
2   {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.1        {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}
3   {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.1}       {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.1}
4   {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.1}       {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.1}
```

Desired results:

```
attributes   categories
0.0          0.0
0.0          0.0
0.1          0.0
0.1          0.1
0.1          0.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try

```
df['attributes']=df['attributes'].str.get('compound')
```